# Delphi XE2 RibbonComboBox can be scrollable?

Tags: delphi, ribbon

How can I make this component scrollable?

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly what you mean

Comment: The list contains about 100 items and does not fit on the screen. The program draws the list from top to bottom of the monitor and some elements are not shown. Neither with keyboard nor mousewheel scrolls the list.